# Thread notification when boost::interprocess::mapped_region is changed

Tags: c++, memory-mapped-files, boost-interprocess

How can I be notified when the bytes in boost::interprocess::mapped_region is changed by using interprocess_condition.

I have opened a file, and have mapped the specific region correctly. When I poll and print the memory, the update has been successful. I now want to be notified of the change rather than continuously polling.

How do I use interprocess_condition to notify my thread the memory has been changed?